# I can't get xmerl_xpath to work for XPath expressions involving namespaces

Tags: xpath, erlang, xml-namespaces

I can't get xmlerl_xpath to find nodes with namespaces.

Given an XML document, e.g.

```
<ostrich:Zebra xmlns:ostrich=\"some-url\"/>
```

and an XPath expression, e.g.

```
/x:Zebra
```

and a namespace map, e.g.

```
"x" => "some-url",
```

how do I use xmerl to parse the document and apply the XPath expression to it?
In the example case, I should end up with the single Zebra node?

This doesn't work:

```
XmlStr = "<ostrich:Zebra xmlns:ostrich=\"some-url\"/>".
{Doc,_} = xmerl_scan:string(XmlStr]).
xmerl_xpath:string("/x:Zebra", Doc, [{namespace, [{"x","some-url"}]}]).
```

but why not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not in the use of xmerl_xpath -- but in the fact that the parsed XML document, Doc, has not had its namespaces resolved.

To make that happen, change your parsing call to

```
{Doc,_} = xmerl_scan:string(XmlStr, [{namespace_conformant, true}]).
```

Then it works:

```
XmlStr = "<ostrich:Zebra xmlns:ostrich=\"some-url\"/>".
{Doc,_} = xmerl_scan:string(XmlStr, [{namespace_conformant, true}]), ok.
length(xmerl_xpath:string("/x:Zebra", Doc, [{namespace, [{"x","some-url"}]}])).
=> 1
```

Comment: In your xml example what is namespace_conformant?  What is namespace?